# static_assert in for-init-statement of the for statement

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

What prevents compilers from compiling a `static_assert` placed in *for-init-statement* of the **for** statement?

For example:

```
for(static_assert(true, ""); false; ); // error
```

Comment: Why do you need it there?

Comment: @Slava As the `Language-Lawyer` tag wiki article says: *"even though your question might otherwise have no practical use"*.

Comment: @Slava no need yet. are compilers demand oriented or standard oriented?

Comment: @rahnema1 standard is demand oriented

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Grammatically](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram). A `for` loop is:

```
for ( init-statement; conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

where an *init-statement* is either an *expression* followed by a `;` or a *simple-declaration*. A *static_assert-declaration* is neither of those things, hence it can't go there.

Comment: but static_assert is a declaration

Comment: @rahnema1 But it's not a *simple-declaration*.

Comment: @rahnema1 a `static_assert` is a *block-declaration* not a *simple-declaration*.